# table and nav with knockout js enable and if statement

Tags: knockout.js

I am using knockout js with two tab buttons. My first  problem is that, I want to enable the tab buttons only if there is data in the tables. Here is my whole code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" nav-justified role="tablist">
            <li id="itemo" class="active"><a  href="#loanInvoice" role="tab"  data-toggle="tab">my loan invoices</a></li>
            <li id="itemr" ><a data-bind="enable: invoicedatasintable().length > 0" href="#investmentInvoice" role="tab"  data-toggle="tab">my investment invoices</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabBorder">
          <div id="tabs" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="loanInvoice">
              <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_invoiced"); ?></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_Paid"); ?></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_Currency"); ?></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_rf"); ?></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("myinvoice_table_type"); ?></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_status"); ?></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay"); ?></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: invoicedatasintable">
                    <tr data-bind="if : $data.type == 2 ">
                        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.invoiced_total"></span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.paid_total "></span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.Abbreviation"></span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.getSelectedInvoice"><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></a></td>
                        <!-- <td><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></td> -->
                        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.type_txt"></span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.status_description"></span></td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" data-bind="if: parseFloat($data.invoiced_total()) > parseFloat($data.paid_total()), click: $root.getRepaymentInvoice"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></a>
                        <span data-bind="ifnot: parseFloat($data.invoiced_total()) > parseFloat($data.paid_total())"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></span>  
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- table-responsive -->
        <div class="pager" data-bind="template:{ name: 'tpl-pager', data: Pagerinvoicedatas }"></div>

            </div>
            <!-- transhistory -->
            <div class="tab-pane" id="investmentInvoice">
              <div class="table-responsive" >
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                 <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_invoiced"); ?></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_Paid"); ?></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_Currency"); ?></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_rf"); ?></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("myinvoice_table_type"); ?></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_status"); ?></th>
                        <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay"); ?></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: invoicedatasintable">
                    <tr data-bind="if : $data.type == 1">
                        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.invoiced_total"></span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.paid_total "></span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.Abbreviation"></span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.getSelectedInvoice"><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></a></td>
                        <!-- <td><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></td> -->
                        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.type_txt"></span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.status_description"></span></td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" data-bind="if: parseFloat($data.invoiced_total()) > parseFloat($data.paid_total()), click: $root.getRepaymentInvoice"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></a>
                        <span data-bind="ifnot: parseFloat($data.invoiced_total()) > parseFloat($data.paid_total())"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></span>  
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
                 <!-- table-responsive -->
        <div class="pager" data-bind="template:{ name: 'tpl-pager', data: Pagerinvoicedatas }"></div>
            </div>
```

I tried putting the enable in different places since it did not work anywhere, I just put it on the `<a>` of the first second `<li>`, I also need the same enable button on the other tab, so it check whichever tab has their table populated that table can be clicked. Second problem, the if statement in the tr, for data.type == 2, it shows me a whole empty table and when i go to the second page using pager I see the data.type 2, which means that most probably its showing data.type ==1 but its hidden I guess not sure. Just to show here is a picture. So when I click page 1 it doesnt show anything but its empty so wondering why did the data go to the second page.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a minimal example, I wrote the snippet below. The arrays are empty, and the 2nd tab is disabled in the sense that the anchor doesn't do anything when you click on it. It still highlights on hover, because that is a Bootstrap behavior. If you put some data in `invoicedatasintable`, the tab becomes clickable.

The thing is, you're using Bootstrap widgets, and you don't have bindings for them. Bootstrap is not made to deal with the way Knockout manipulates the DOM (and vice-versa). You need custom binding handlers. There is a [Knockout-Bootstrap library](https://github.com/billpull/knockout-bootstrap) that provides a good set of them, but you may still have to write some of your own.

```js
vm = {
  invoicedatasintable: ko.observableArray([]),
  Pagerinvoicedatas: []
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" nav-justified role="tablist">
  <li id="itemo" class="active"><a href="#loanInvoice" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">my loan invoices</a>
  </li>
  <li id="itemr"><a data-bind="enable: invoicedatasintable().length > 0" href="#investmentInvoice" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">my investment invoices</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tabBorder">
  <div id="tabs" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="loanInvoice">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_invoiced"); ?>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_Paid"); ?>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_Currency"); ?>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_rf"); ?>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "myinvoice_table_type"); ?>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_status"); ?>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_pay"); ?>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: invoicedatasintable">
            <tr data-bind="if : $data.type == 2 ">
              <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.invoiced_total"></span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.paid_total "></span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.Abbreviation"></span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.getSelectedInvoice"><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></a>
              </td>
              <!-- <td><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></td> -->
              <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.type_txt"></span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.status_description"></span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <a href="#" data-bind="if: parseFloat($data.invoiced_total()) > parseFloat($data.paid_total()), click: $root.getRepaymentInvoice">
                  <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_pay1"); ?>
                </a>
                <span data-bind="ifnot: parseFloat($data.invoiced_total()) > parseFloat($data.paid_total())"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!-- table-responsive -->
      <div class="pager" data-bind="template:{ name: 'tpl-pager', data: Pagerinvoicedatas }"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- transhistory -->
    <div class="tab-pane" id="investmentInvoice">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_invoiced"); ?>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_Paid"); ?>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_Currency"); ?>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_rf"); ?>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "myinvoice_table_type"); ?>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_status"); ?>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center">
                <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_pay"); ?>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: invoicedatasintable">
            <tr data-bind="if : $data.type == 1">
              <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.invoiced_total"></span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.paid_total "></span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.Abbreviation"></span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.getSelectedInvoice"><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></a>
              </td>
              <!-- <td><span data-bind="text: $data.rf_reference"></span></td> -->
              <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.type_txt"></span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.status_description"></span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <a href="#" data-bind="if: parseFloat($data.invoiced_total()) > parseFloat($data.paid_total()), click: $root.getRepaymentInvoice">
                  <?php echo lang( "invoice_table_pay1"); ?>
                </a>
                <span data-bind="ifnot: parseFloat($data.invoiced_total()) > parseFloat($data.paid_total())"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!-- table-responsive -->
      <div class="pager" data-bind="template:{ name: 'tpl-pager', data: Pagerinvoicedatas }"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ray J, I get that bootstrap is messing up with the nav but you got any idea why when i write data.type == 2, I get a whole empty table and when i click number two on the buttons below it goes to the next page where i see 1 row, but that 1 row of data should be on the first page of the pager

Comment: No, I don't know what is going on there.

Comment: is it possible to check a string like now I wrote $data.type ==1 is it possible I can check a string like data-bind=" if:  $data.type == 'Invest' " ? is writing like this even possible?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You don't need `$data.` just `type`

Comment: It's really just like you said: `<div data-bind="if: type == 'Invest'">`*stuff that displays conditionally*`</div>`

Comment: okay so we just cancel out the $data part ? alright thanks for the info :D